# Detecting the notch in more details in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, responsive-design, flexbox

I searched & checked these 2 links

[React-Native Detect Screen Notch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51858807/react-native-detect-screen-notch)

https://github.com/ovr/react-native-status-bar-height

what I got , I can detect the notch height , but I'd like to know more details

how much height in top and in bottom

because my current device has a bottom notch , and IPhone X has notch in top & bottom with different height size in each side

using SafeAreraView did not help

Please check the attached image

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RC9LH.jpg)

Comment: why did safeAreaView not help?

Comment: @tudor.gergely , when I used it and tested through my mobile device , the element was behind the bottom notch

Comment: what is the bottom notch you are talking about? can you show me a picture?

Comment: @tudor.gergely , I updated my answer with the image - please check it

Comment: I see, that is not a notch, it is the navbar. Do you want to display something fullscreen?

Comment: @tudor.gergely yes , in Expo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Expo 36 has the fullscreen option on android especially (hiding the bottom navbar). It will be available in the next release it seems: https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/7049

You should wait for the next expo release and try it then (instructions in the above PR):

```
in app.json
{
  androidNavigationBar: {
    visible: 'leanback' // or some other type you want
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer helped , but till now it only support true and false - advanced features like 'leaseback' , 'immersive' and 'sticky' will help